# How to pass a parameter to a function from a class that has already a running instance with getattr - Python

Tags: python, string, function, selenium, getattr

I have a selenium web scraping object called `Bot()`.

In my GUI I want to call methods via an input box. I have tried:

```
bot = bot_module.Bot()

function_string = "somefunction(parameter)"
func_name = function_string.split("(")[0]
func_param = function_string.split("(")[-1].split(")")[0]
func = getattr(opus,func_name)
func(func_param)
```

This raises a `valueError` as defined in somefunction. Going a different way:

```
getattr(globals()['Bot'](),func_name)(func_param)
```

I get the error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Session is already started.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would try to use the `re` module to extract the function name and arguments from such a string, but I would much prefer to avoid having to parse such a string in the first place, and get the function name and the arguments as *separate* strings.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer and sorry for spamming!

In my function I had declared:

````
   if param1 not in valid:
     raise ValueError(f"Param1 has to be in: {valid}")```

...and since I was passing the param as a string it raised the error.
````